# Python modulo returning wrong answer

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, modulo

I was attempting [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-dice-rolls-with-target-sum/) on leetcode using python3.
My solution for this problem is as follows:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.memo = {}
        
    def numRollsToTarget(self, d: int, f: int, target: int) -> int:
        
        if target < d or target > d*f: return 0
        if d == 1:
            if target<=f: return 1
            else: return 0
        
        
        key = d+f+target

        if key not in self.memo:
            total = 0
            for i in range(1,f+1):
                if key not in self.memo:
                    total += self.numRollsToTarget(d-1,f,target-i)
            self.memo[key] = total%((10**9) + 7)
        return self.memo[key]
```

My solution works for small inputs like:
`Input: n = 1, k = 6, target = 3 Output: 1 Explanation: You throw one die with 6 faces. There is only one way to get a sum of 3.`
However inputs such as
`Input: n = 30, k = 30, target = 500 Output: 222616187 Explanation: The answer must be returned modulo 109 + 7.` 
do not pass the test cases, even when I have made sure that I return the modulo answer. `For example for the second test case, the correct output is 222616187. However, my code returns 146996393.`  Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`d+f+target` is not a unique key for the tuple `(d, f, target)`, which makes the memoization yield incorrect results. Using the tuple `(d, f, target)` itself is a simple fix.

Also it is unclear why there is a second `if key not in self.memo:` *inside* the loop. It shouldn't be possible for that condition to be changed by the computation of the sub-problems, and if it *was* possible then it would be the wrong way to do it because the wrong `total` is added up and written over the memo entry that apparently exists.